# Error while executing AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My app works fine when it is connected to internet, 
but when there is no internet connection it crashes.

```
public static final String URL =
        "http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png";
ImageView imageView;

ImageButton imageButton;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageButton=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imgb);
    // Create an object for subclass of AsyncTask
    GetXMLTask task = new GetXMLTask();
    // Execute the task
    task.execute(new String[] { URL });
}

private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap map = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            map = downloadImage(url);
        }
        return map;
    }

    // Sets the Bitmap returned by doInBackground
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imageButton.setImageBitmap(result);
    }

    // Creates Bitmap from InputStream and returns it
    private Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        InputStream stream = null;
        BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

        try {
            stream = getHttpConnection(url);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.
                    decodeStream(stream, null, bmOptions);
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    // Makes HttpURLConnection and returns InputStream
    private InputStream getHttpConnection(String urlString)
            throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = null;
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();

        try {
            HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
            httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            httpConnection.connect();

            if (httpConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                stream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }
}
```

logcat:

```
08-30 21:22:08.325  32554-32577/com.android.cardview E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.android.cardview, PID: 32554
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.InputStream.close()' on a null object reference
            at com.android.cardview.ImageViewFromURLActivity$GetXMLTask.downloadImage(ImageViewFromURLActivity.java:80)
            at com.android.cardview.ImageViewFromURLActivity$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(ImageViewFromURLActivity.java:52)
            at com.android.cardview.ImageViewFromURLActivity$GetXMLTask.doInBackground(ImageViewFromURLActivity.java:43)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Comment: Obvious that the url `http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/totlogo.png` will be not reachable, if there is no internet connection.

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand?

Comment: Your `AsyncTask` performs a function for which it NEEDS internet. So, it's quite obvious that it'll crash when no internet connection is available. If you don't want it to crash first check if the device is connected to the internet, then proceed towards executing the `AsyncTask`

Comment: handle exception in do in background and do accordingly in post execute without returning any null value

Comment: i have used internet permission, app crashes when it does not have internet connection , it works fine when it is connected to internet

Answer (score 1):

You MUST have Internet access to get that image, if not null exception will happen.

To know if you have connection or not, you must use something like this:

```
public static boolean testConection(Context context){
        boolean HaveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean HaveConnectedMobile = false;
        boolean result;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo)
        {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    HaveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    HaveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        result = HaveConnectedWifi || HaveConnectedMobile;
        return result;
    }
```

Put it on a Utils class or similar. Then, in your main Activity (or Fragment, doesn't matter) use it like this:

```
boolean connready = Utils.testConection(getActivity());
        if (connready) {
            // Here goes your code if connection is true
            task.execute(new String[] { URL });
        } else {
            // Here you can send alerts to users without connection
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
```

That'll be more UX friendly for users. Hope that helps you!